# how to free dfs space in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have emptied a column from 25 million rows in hbase. 
Do i need to do compaction on table to regain unused space in hbase.

Current dfs usage is 93% used and unable to launch a job.

Any ideas how to regain space ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try running a major compaction to see if that fixes it. You might also be hitting [HBASE-6564](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-6564) issue which was fixed in 0.95.0.